# Oracle Database LOB increases untypical

Tags: oracle, blob

An Oracle 12c production database includes tables with a BLOB column. Usually the growth rate is 2GB per week. This is the table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE XXX.FILEENTRY
(
  FILENAME     VARCHAR2(300 CHAR),
  FILESIZE     NUMBER(20),
  FILECONTENT  BLOB
)
LOB (FILECONTENT) STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE  DATA
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  CACHE
  LOGGING
      STORAGE    (
                  INITIAL          104K
                  NEXT             1M
                  MINEXTENTS       1
                  MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                  PCTINCREASE      0
                  BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                 ))
TABLESPACE DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;
```

Since some days the LOB increases up to 100GB a day. The LOB which increases that fast is: SYS_LOB0000119621C00011$$:

```
Owner,Segment name,Segment size (GB)
xxx,FILEENTRY,1,8
xxx,SYS_LOB0000119621C00011$$, 1156,1
```

The application has a transfer table which only shows the usual input of about 2GB a week. What could be the reason for this growth if this is not coming from the users? Is there a way to check the content of SYS_LOB0000119621C00011$$?

Comment: What makes you think the data isn't coming from the users? There's no reason the database would allocate space it doesn't need.

Comment: @AndrewBrennan That is how software would work, ideally. Actually, there is only 1 platform on which Oracle works flawlessly, which is: Powerpoint.

Comment: @BalazsPapp Sure there are sometimes bugs, but that doesn't neccessarily mean this is a bug, it may be expected behaviour

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to check the content of SYS_LOB0000119621C00011$$?

Yes you can first look at dba_lobs view to check which table/column is associated with this segment.

> What could be the reason for this growth if this is not coming from
>   the users?

Maybe one huge file has been inserted in your table. You can use DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(column_name) to find the size of each lob.

```
select filename, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(filecontent) from fileentry order by 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at (Oracle Support content, requires subscription):

[LOB segment size is significantly increasing despite of small actual size of data in it (Doc ID 2326423.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2326423.1)

There are 3 bugs in it that have one-off patches for 12c (they are fixed in 18c):

- **Bug 26007010** : DATABASE GREW EVEN THOUGH RESOURCES DELETED
- **Bug 26439748** : ENQ: TX - CONTENTION AND GC BUFFER BUSY ACQUIRE WAITS ON SECUREFILES IN 12.1
- **Bug 26513067** : ASSIGNMENT OF INSTANCE AFFINITY FLAWED IN KTSLA_HBB_UPDATE_CACHE

And some hidden parameters as well to set.

Here is the public version of that note (not the full content):

[LOB segment size is significantly increasing despite of small actual size of data in it (Doc ID 2326423.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2326423_1.html)

> **SYMPTOMS**
>
> - A LOB segment is of size around few hundreds of GB when it is actually of around few hundred of MB only.

Comment: The bug fixes can only be applied on Linux. No fix for other platforms yet.